# Collection View Controller crashing and not returning images

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cloudkit

I am building a Collection View to return images from a CloudKit database.  The results are returning slowly, but they are returning.  However, I am getting the classic "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error and I  can't figure out why or what I have to fix to solve the error.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this problem?

My code is as follows:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController  {

@IBOutlet var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var image = UIImage()
var matchedSelfie =  [UIImage]()
let reuseIdentifier = "MyCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   // self.canDisplayBannerAds = true


    println("Loading")

    var countedImages = matchedSelfie
    let publicDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    print(publicDB)

    let data = CKRecord(recordType: "theUsers")
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
    let myQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "theUsers", predicate: pred)


    publicDB.performQuery(myQuery, inZoneWithID: nil) {
        results, error in
        println("Results from publicDB Query: \(results)")

        if error != nil {
            println(error)

        } else {
            for record in results {
                if var aselfie = record.objectForKey("selfie") as CKAsset! {
                    if var url = aselfie.fileURL {
                        var imageData = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path!)!
                       self.matchedSelfie.append(imageData)
                    }

                    println(self.matchedSelfie)
                    println("total selfies: \(self.matchedSelfie.count)")
                    var cellscount = self.matchedSelfie.count
                    }
                }
            }


    println("Done Loading")
     self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }//View Did Load

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: Int) -> Int {
    self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    return 1
}


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: Int) -> Int {
        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    println("Selfies: \(self.matchedSelfie.count)")
    println(matchedSelfie.count)
     myCollectionView.reloadData()
    return self.matchedSelfie.count

    }



     override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell
        println("just seeing when this prints")
        cell.amatchedSelfie.image = image
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know which line it fails? And what is the value of image at time of assigning it to cell.amatchedSelfie.image? Probably you can check for nil before assigning to cell.amatchedSelfie.image

Comment: It crashes on the line:
   
   'cell.amatchedSelfie.image = image'

I don't know how to check for nil.

Comment: assign image to cell.amatchedSelfie.image only if it is not nil

Comment: if cell.amatchedSelfie != nil {
                cell.amatchedSelfie.image = image
                return cell
            } else {
            println("error")
                return cell
            }